# Why might C# code run much slower on a server than a development machine?

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, performance, windows-services

I have a block of code which reads n rows from a file, loads them into a temp table in MySQL, performs some cleansing and comparison with other data, then does an update on that other data depending on the cleansing results.

It is deployed as a Windows service. It uses multi-threading at one point. It relies on issuing commands to MySql in an old fashioned way, executing commands and calling stored procedures rather than using an ORM such as Entity Framework.

The code runs fine. What's baffling me is the comparative performance when I've run it on the server vs running my local code in debug mode. Here's what I'm logging:

```
int blockSize = 5000;

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// reads [blockSize] rows from file and appends a cleansed version to each
sw.Stop();
_log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to CLEAN DATA {1} rows", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, blockSize));

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
// bulk copies the rows into a temp table in MySQL
sw.Stop();
_log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to LOAD DATA {1} rows", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, blockSize));

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
// multi-threaded code which runs through the temp table and gives each record an updateId
sw.Stop();
_log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to COMPARE DATA {1} rows", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, blockSize));

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
// executes a MySQL command to update another table using the updateId determined above
sw.Stop();
_log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to SAVE DATA {1} rows", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, blockSize));
```

And here's how quickly one iteation performs on my local machine, which has 4 cores and 8GB of RAM. It's talking to a development MySql Server for the db work, not a local installation:

- Took 12643 ms to CLEAN DATA 5000 rows
- Took 349 ms to LOAD DATA 5000 rows
- Took 11864 ms to COMPARE DATA 5000 rows
- Took 940 ms to SAVE DATA 5000 rows

And here's how long it takes when the same code is deployed as a service on the same 8 core, 16GB RAM development machine that's running the DB:

- Took 174 ms to CLEAN DATA 5000 rows
- Took 293 ms to LOAD DATA 5000 rows
- Took 461566 ms to COMPARE DATA 5000 rows
- Took 130 ms to SAVE DATA 5000 rows

As you can see, the comparison step is 38 times slower on a much more powerful machine while everything else is slightly faster.

That server is working hard while it does this, but it's not maxing out CPU or RAM or Disk. It isn't doing much else in the background apart from normal windows functions. It is a virtual server and it ran an (older) version of this code fine, but has been slow doing this since, allegedly, being given more cores and RAM to play with. This isn't a one-off: although that's just one set of data, repeat testing shows similar patterns.

At a loss to explain what's going on here. I can only imagine it's one of:

- The fact this is happening in he only multi-threaded part of the application, but that should be faster, not slower.
- The fact it's been given more VM cores and RAM though this should also make it faster.
- The fact it's deployed as a Windows service instead of debugging in VS
- The fact it's executing on the same machine that's running the DB

But none of those make much sense. Can anyone suggest a possible cause? Or how can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is there a lot of traffic on the server?

Comment: @CptMisery Nope. It's basically my captive development server and it's not doing much else at all.

Comment: @CptMisery Just remembered - it's a VM and it got given some extra cores and memory a little while ago. That may be related as it used perform better before the "update".

Comment: I really don't know. I would try setting it up as a service locally to see if it runs slower. It would at least tell you if it is a problem with it running as a service or if it's a problem with something on the server

Comment: Sorry you haven't found any help here. If you do find the problem I would like to know what it is. Been a long time since I created a service or something multi-threaded in .NET.

Comment: What vm software are you using? And which processor etc? I heard of a case Where vmware on AMD cpu was running slow because of a bios setting in de vm server host

Comment: Were both on Windows?  Or was one *nix?  Take the delta in `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and see if the number of tmp tables is different.  Are the disk subsystems different?  Which one is a VM?  Build a table of the differences, please.

Comment: In your debug scenario, the service and the MySQL engine run on different machines, in the deployment scenario on the same machine: that might be just to much of work for that machine.

Comment: @BernhardHiller It's not maxed out. Not by a long way. Running at ~60% CPU distributed across all cores and 4.5GB out of 16 in memory.

Comment: @MattThrower Don't forget disc IO which might be much slower, and is quite hard to see with virtual machines.